# Don't understand how it can be IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python

I've seen this error report commented on and answered in other posts but I can't find the reason why this should happen in this scenario.

This is my code .  A code that's been used millions of times in coding?
(I should add the exact same code has run fine many times but not today)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

standings_url = "https://fbref.com/en/comps/9/Premier-League-Stats"
data = requests.get(standings_url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text)
standings_table = soup.select('table.stats_table')[0]
```

I get the error message :

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[6], line 1
1 standings_table = soup.select('table.stats_table')[0]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

I don't understand how it can be out of range?   Aren't I looking at [0] ?

Could you explain the error to be at a very basic level that I can understand please.  What can I add to the code to stop this repeating?

Many thanks

Comment: If the call to `.select()` returns an empty list - for example, if the web page's HTML has changed - then trying to index even the first entry will be a problem - there are no entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens that I get a good looking table ATM, with no error.

> how it can be out of range?

The webserver is not sending back a constant document.
It may alter the document contents for many reasons,
for example due to a broken backend sports feed,
due to large number of client requests from your IP address,
or due to a CAPTCHA challenge.

Sometimes that BS4 selector doesn't find anything.
Let's reproduce the error, using a "typo" selector which won't match.

```
>>> standings_table = soup.select('table.stats_table')[0]
>>> standings_table = soup.select('table.Ztats_table')[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
>>> 
>>> soup.select('table.Ztats_table')
[]
```

In the situation where there is no match,
we get back an empty list.
And there is no initial element, no `0`-th element,
in an empty list.
So an exception is raised.

> What can I add to the code to stop this repeating?

Examine `len(soup.select('table.stats_table'))`.
If it is greater than zero, all is well.
If zero, then tell the user "sorry!"
and move on.

Each time you successfully retrieve
a stats table HTML document,
you are free to cache it in your local filesystem.
When you sometimes retrieve an unusable document,
it might be preferable to fall back to
using the old cached document.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the soup doesn't have any such tag.

[image]

I printed the soup before finding the tag and tried to look for stats_table class in the HTML response, but its not there.
So ofcourse it would be an empty response and if you are again trying to access 0th index, then its index out of range error.

I don't think you can use web scrapping on this particular page anymore because of this intermediate bad guy.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The code of

```
soup.select('table.stats_table')[0]
```

searches for `table` elements which have the `stats_table` class. The result is 0-indexed, so your indexes are natural numbers

**between 0 and length - 1**

Since you are referring to `[0]` and it's out of range, it means that

**0 > length - 1**

therefore

**length is 0**

which means that no such element was found.

This means that at the time you are running your code, the elements you are searching for are not there - yet. Therefore, you will need to find out when they are ready and load them at that point.